# carouFredsel thumbnail implementation and IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, implementation

I have implemented carouFredSel (with the basic example with next/prev and pagination) into Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and 8. For some reason though when viewing IE7 it seems to me that the plugin does not fire right. It just shows the list going down and does not put it into oveflow hidden or a line where the next and previous buttons will work. Is there something I am missing here?

I have looked through the installation several times and also tried to implement this on IE7 on a standalone page and was unable to. As well, I have looked thorugh the configuration and custom events and ie7 developer toolbar. It seems that the plugin is just not setting up the correct things on IE7 as it does create the class/id's foo2 and iamge_carousel.  Does anyone have a different IE7 to try incase it is some settings on my IE7 VHD or help point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time.
Kamron

EDIT:   http://www.kamsshowcase.com/stws-wp/?page_id=114

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the source, your conditional comment is incorrect. you need a space between **IE** and **7**.

You have:

```
<!--[if lte IE7]>
<link rel="stlesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kamsshowcase.com/stws-wp/wp-content/themes/stws/inc/style_ie6.css"></script<![endif]-->
```

You need:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stlesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kamsshowcase.com/stws-wp/wp-content/themes/stws/inc/style_ie6.css"></script<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure how I missed that.  Everything seems to be working fine now.